# Android Should I modify view elements or reload the Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I've built a View which displays data driven by the respective Java Activity class. The data comes from the first `element` of a `Collection`.

On a button click from the view (`onClick`), I want to display the second element of the `Collection` in the view (replacing the first `element`).

What is the best way to achieve this? Here is what I was thinking:

1. `onClick` invokes a method in the Activity class which modifies the state of existing view elements?
2. `onClick` reloads the Activity and the state of the `Collection` still exists to be able to present?
3. Some other way?

Not sure if 1 will work as the Model isn't bound to the view elements? Some kind of refresh will be needed.

2 sounds overkill if you just want to keep the view structure the same but modify the state of elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just bind the elements to the Collection again, it will be the fastest as no new views are initialized

Comment: use array adapter istead. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Iago. I think this means try option 1? I believe when I tried this, I got an IllegalStateException (I think) when trying to modify the elements second time around.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood and there is a particular way to bind these elements. At the moment I'm just using findViewById(R.id.txtArea); and then setting attributes on the returned object.

Comment: @DegenSharew - ArrayAdapter seems more geared towards when you want to display all elements in a collection up front?
Whereas, I want to show one element at a time.
Would you nice to see an example of what you mean if that's not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewSwitcher

```
  <ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewswitcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="firstClick" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        android:onClick="secondClick"

</ViewSwitcher>
```

In java code

```
firstClick()
{

    viewswitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
}


secondClick()
{

   //whatever you need
}
```

Here when you click on a the first view(It can be a button), the second view can be made visible by replacing the first one. Use it as per your convenience.

Comment: I don't think this is scalable? What if my collection contains many elements? Also as described everything about the view is the same, just the data within it will be modified.

Comment: both the view can be a layout itself. You can add a collection of data within a layout. And it may be scalable as per  your requirement. If it cant meet your requirement,sorry for that.  use another method.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking this. All I had to do was update the state of the view objects in the java layer and the view would automatically 'paint' the changes.